# Is it Possible through python or with any other language to archive the daily downloaded files into one folder

Tags: python, shell, scripting-language

I need a utility to archive my daily downloaded files into one new folder.

Suppose, I downloaded 10 files today and at the end of the day, all the files should get archived into one new folder with name **Archived_TodaysDate.**

THIS ACTIVITY/TASK CAN BE SCHEDULABLE AND EXECUTE ON DAILY BASIS.

IT WOULD BE GOOD IF YOU HELP IN THE CONTEXT OF MAC OPERATING SYSTEM.

I know this can be done through many scripting languages but I wanted to know for mac which scripting language is good for this task and a quick start guide.

Comment: It's possible to implement this using any scripting language. Python would be a good choice. You can find the Python tutorial here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Comment: The [os](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html) module will also be particularly useful for this task

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't familiar with setting up a chrontab you can set those up by following [this](https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/schedule-jobs-with-crontab-on-mac-osx.html) (I looked for a mac-specific one but there are zillions of guides about this.)

Your archiving script can be quite simple. Begin by generating a list of files to archive (refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087693/python-code-to-find-all-newly-created-modified-and-deleted-files-in-all-the-dir) answer.)

```
import datetime as dt
import time
import os
import zipfile

now = dt.datetime.now()
ago = now-dt.timedelta(days=1)
```

Unlike in the referenced answer we want a list of files, not a `print`ed output. So we initialize a list and `append` to it at each iteration. Here I assume that your script lives **in** your downloads folder, but you can change the path given to `os.walk` as appropriate.

```
to_archive = []

for root, dirs,files in os.walk('.'):  
    for fname in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, fname)
        st = os.stat(path)    
        mtime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_mtime)
        if mtime > ago:
            to_archive.append(path)
```

We also want a `strftime` representation of `now` for our archive file title.

```
ts = now.strftime("%m_%d_%Y")
```

Finally write the files into an archive file (in this case I chose `zip` format).

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('{}_archive.zip'.format(ts), 'w') as myzip:
    for x in to_archive:    
      myzip.write(x)
```